# what does -1 represent in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

```
function first(first, second) {
    return Array.prototype.every.call(first, function(c) {
        return second.indexOf(c) > -1;
    }, this);
}
```

everything works perfectly, but I don't really understand what ".indexOf(c) > -1" is in the function

Comment: [_"The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present."_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: `>` is a comparison operator used to see if the first operand is greater than the second one. The answer to a question like that must be `true` or `false`, so the system is testing to see if `second.indexOf(c)` is a value that is greater than `-1` and whichever answer you get (`true` or `false`) is then returned to the caller of the `first` function. **`indexOf` will return the index position within an array of whatever you are searching for within the array or -1 if it doesn't exist.**

Comment: "everything works perfectly" um no, it almost certainly doesn't. It accepts disparate types for the inputs: anything that implements the `Symbol.iterator` protocol can be used for the first argument, and the second argument could be a string, an array, or any object with an `.indexOf` method. You can call `first(new Set([1,2,3]), "12")` and it will return `true` if that's how you swing. The name does not reflect the semantics, `isSubset` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Because if indexof equal -1 it means that the element c doesn't exist in the array named "second". So basically if the element "c" exist in that array it will return the index of that element which is bigger than -1 which make that statement true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The method `.indexOf(c)` searches for the sub string c, in the case of a string, or element c, in the case of an array. If the sub string or element is not found the method returns -1. When the method returns a value greater than -1, this simply means that the sub string or element was found.

`second.indexOf(c) > -1` also equivalent to `second.includes(c)`:

- **[`String#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)**

> The indexOf() method, given one argument: a substring to search for,
> searches the entire calling string, and returns the index of the first
> occurrence of the specified substring. Given a second argument: a
> number, the method returns the first occurrence of the specified
> substring at an index greater than or equal to the specified number.

Let us say,

```
second = "sample" 
//and 
c = "a"
```

We have

```
second.indexOf(c) is 1 //because "a" is at index 1 in "sample"
//therefore 
second.indexOf(c) > -1 is true 
//also
second.includes(c) is true
```

If, however,

`c = "z"`, then `second.indexOf(c)` is `-1` and `second.indexOf(c) > -1` is `false`; `second.includes(c)`, in this case, returns `false`.

- **[`Array#indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)**

> The indexOf() method returns the first index at which a given element
> can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present.

If,

```
second = [4,6,7,9,10,30];
c = 9;
d = 45;
```

then,

```
second.indexOf(c) > -1 is true 
//and
second.indexOf(d) > -1 is false
```

Also,

```
second.includes(c) is true;
//and
second.includes(d) is false;
```